# Plot two xaxis in one plot?

Tags: r, plot

This can be plotted very easily.

```
xvals <- c(5.5, 15.5, 25.5, 35.5, 45.5, 55.5, 65.5, 75.5, 85.5, 95.5)
yvals <- c(81, 63, 45, 27, 9, -9, -27, -45, -63, -81)
xn <- rep(1000, 10)
plot(xvals, yvals)
```

Both xvals and xn share the same yvals so I want to plot in one graph:

```
   yaxis:
   xaxis lower:xvals
   xaxis upper:xn
```

[image]

I simply want to add `xn` to the same plot as an xaxis (the upper) axis(3).
Any idea on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave your code as it is up to `plot(xvals, yvals)`. Then add the following:

```
#plot the first plot
plot(xvals, yvals)
#start new overlaid plot
par(new=TRUE)
#plot xn but remove the xaxis and the x label for now
plot(xn, yvals, xaxt='n', xlab='')
#add those at the top of the graph (3)
axis(3, xn)
#bonus. add this line to add a secondary xlabel on top
mtext(side = 3, line = 2, "xn")
```

Result:

[image]